# Accessing Subpage Model properties in template file Wagtail

Tags: python-2.7, wagtail

here is my model.py file

```
...

class LinkFields(models.Model):
    link_external = models.URLField(
        "External link",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text='Set an external link if you want to describe the event from an other web site',
    )
    link_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Choose an existing page (event must have already been created)',
    )

    @property
    def link(self):
        if self.link_page:
            return self.link_page.url
        else:
            return self.link_external

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('link_external'),
        PageChooserPanel('link_page'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class RelatedLink(LinkFields):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Link title")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        MultiFieldPanel(LinkFields.panels, "Link"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related events"),
    ]


class EventsPage(Page):

    # Database fields

    date = models.DateField("Event date")
    topicTag = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default="Where it is")
    place = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    # Search index configuration

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + (
        index.SearchField('topicTag'),
        index.SearchField('place'),
        index.FilterField('date'),
    )

    # Editor panels configuration

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('topicTag'),
        FieldPanel('name', classname="title"),
        FieldPanel('city'),
        FieldPanel('place'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
    ]


class EventsRelatedLink(Orderable, RelatedLink):
    page = ParentalKey('HomePage', related_name='related_links')
```

EventsPages are subpages of HomePage, which itself display links of subsequent subpages. My problem is for each subpage's link I display on the homepage I would like to access properties of the the so-called subpage in order to display a kind of preview.

Here is my home_page.html template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>THE <span class="pink">OPEN SOURCE</span> INNOVATION SPRING</h1>

   <div class="intro">{{ page.body|richtext }}</div>

   {% if page.related_links.all %}
      <ul>
    {% for item in page.related_links.all %}
       <li><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
       <br><div class="description">{{ item.date }}
         <span class="pink">[{{ item.topicTag }}]</span>
          {{ item.name }} <span class="pink">[{{ item.city }}]</span>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and of course all the "item.*" with * as properties of EventsPage Model, does not work. I'm quite sure I'm in the wrong way but please I need help to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `{{ item.date }}` won't work because `item` is a `RelatedLink` object, not a page object. To access the page object, you would need `{{ item.link_page.date }}` (and, of course, some alternative behaviour for when the editor has provided `link_external` instead of `link_page`). However, this change won't be enough by itself - it will work for the core page properties like `item.link_page.title`, but not the event-specific ones like `date`.

An explanation of why this happens: whenever you retrieve a set of pages, through an operation like `EventPage.objects.all()`, or `page.get_children()` or (in this case) `page.related_links`, then normally all the results will be of the same type. If it's an operation that could potentially cover several different types of page (for example - `EventPage.objects.all()` can only ever return EventPage objects, but `page.get_children()` or `page.related_links` could return any kind of page), then in order to keep them all the same, it has to return them as the "lowest common denominator" - the basic Page model that all page types descend from. This provides the fields such as `title` that are common to all pages, but none of the special-purpose fields.

(This is a limitation of the way database lookups work - if we wanted to fetch each page object in its most specific form, the database query would have to check all of the page-related tables at once, which is massively inefficient.)

With that in mind, there are a couple of options available to you:

Firstly, if you know that the editors on your site will only ever select `EventPage`s as related links - and it seems like this is a safe assumption to make, based on your help_text and the fact that you're writing things like `{{ item.date }}` and `{{ item.city }}` which probably wouldn't make sense for other kinds of page - then you can enforce this at the database level by making the foreign key point to `EventPage`:

```
link_page = models.ForeignKey(
    'myapp.EventPage',  # replace 'myapp' with your application name
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    related_name='+',
    help_text='Choose an existing page (event must have already been created)',
)
```

With this change in place, the page chooser in the Wagtail admin will only allow you to select `EventPage`s for this field, and `item.link_page` will give you full `EventPage` objects, allowing you to write `{{ item.link_page.date }}`.

Secondly: if you need to support other page types in the related links - for example, maybe you have a `NewsPage` model that also has a `date` field, and want to be able to select these as related links too - then you can convert the basic `Page` object into the more specific page type by calling `.specific` on it. For example: `{{ item.link_page.specific.date }}`. The drawback is that `.specific` will perform an extra database lookup every time you use it, which might harm performance. As a simple optimisation, you can use a `{% with %}` tag to assign it to a variable:

```
{% for item in page.related_links.all %}
   {% with item.link_page.specific as related_page %}
      <li><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
      <br><div class="description">{{ related_page.date }}
        <span class="pink">[{{ related_page.topicTag }}]</span>
         {{ related_page.name }} <span class="pink">[{{ related_page.city }}]</span>
      </div>
   {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it solved my problem and you made me understand more precisely how it works. Thank you very much